# SKPhysicsContact isnt removing enemy after contact

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

My bullet is finally being removed after touching the enemy however the enemy isnt being removed. Is something wrong with my physicscontact code? My player is also now going out of the screen border but i just fixed that by removing both bodyB and bodyA nil lines. I dont know if thats the best way to fix the 2nd problem and if it will mess up my enemy code in the future.

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
          if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == bulletCategory) {
            contact.bodyA.node?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
            contact.bodyA.node?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0
          } else if (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == bulletCategory) {
            contact.bodyB.node?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
            contact.bodyB.node?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0
          }
            
            if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == enemyCategory {
                 contact.bodyB.node?.removeFromParent()
                 contact.bodyB.node?.physicsBody = nil
                 contact.bodyB.node?.removeAllActions()
               } else if contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == enemyCategory {
                 contact.bodyA.node?.removeFromParent()
                 contact.bodyA.node?.physicsBody = nil
                 contact.bodyA.node?.removeAllActions()
               }
      }
```

Comment: Show your `didMove` function.

Comment: i dont have anything in did move function for enemy and player. Should i show my enemy function instead?

Comment: You are using 'if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == enemyCategory' which is bodyA, but then removing bodyB. Likewise with bodyB being enemy, but removing bodyA. If bodyA is enemy, do you not want to remove bodyA?

Comment: removing bodyB actually does work but now my missile and player wont get removed, so it just switched. On top of that my enemy doesnt always get removed if it gets contacted but i think its my physicsbody that i messed up. Sometimes my bullet will skim my enemy or even a direct hit and it wont be removed. Other times my bullet can be right beside my enemy and it gets removed

Comment: I'm not sure why you are setting the collision bitmasks in didBegin Contact, that is probably the root of the issue. The bitmasks should all be set just after you create the node, possibly in didMove to view.

Comment: Thats the only way my contact will work. Ive tried setting my didbegin contact differently and it didnt work without my collisions inside. My collisions are set in my functions but not in did move if that makes a difference